# Pure CSS Masonry Layout without defined columns

Tags: css, flexbox, masonry

[image]

I wrote a layout as depicted above. I implemented this with the simple usage of `display: inline-block` and `article` elements that have different widths and heights, like so:

```
width: 50%; /* this is variable*/
height: 160px;  /* this is also variable*/
padding: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

Now this already works quite okish, but: You see the gap above boxes `4` and `5`? Can I write a pure CSS layout that makes these boxes fill up the space directly below `1`? I saw some flex-box solutions but they seemed to work with a fixed set of columns, ideally I just want to pass boxes 1-6 in the layout and they adjust properly. Is that possible with modern CSS? I have no browser restrictions and can work with any modern feature!

Comment: Totally possible but CSS Grid is what you're looking for. It would be worth your time to take this class, covers this exact type of layout: https://cssgrid.io/

Comment: Very related: [CSS-only masonry layout but with elements ordered horizontally](//stackoverflow.com/q/44377343)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't accomplish that with flexbox and I think grid layout would also not do the thing. [Pure CSS masonry layout is highly expected, but not yet available.](https://regisphilibert.com/blog/2017/12/pure-css-masonry-layout-with-flexbox-grid-columns-in-2018/)

I see two solutions:

1.
Use external package. I would suggest [`react-grid-layout`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-layout) which uses JS to control `position: absolute` and `transform: translate` values of children. It supports resizing and many other features. In your situation it should work just fine.

2.
You could also use [some tiny JS](https://codepen.io/inorganik/pen/pREYPJ) (pen's not mine):

Answer (score 0):

@staypuftman pointed out in a comment to use CSS grids and I accomplished what I wanted to do. This is my code:

On the container:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
grid-gap: 15px;
height: 100vh;
```

what I do is I use the grid layout, I create 8 columns by writing 1fr 8 times in `grid-template-columns` and 12 rows with the 12 `fr`s in the `grid-template-rows` property. Also I set a `grid-gap` for spacing between each item and a height of 100vh to make my grid span over the whole visible space.

Now within my items I do this:

```
grid-column-end: span 2;
grid-row-end: span 2;
```

Where `grid-column-end: span X` tells the browser to span the item over 2 of my columns (of which I created 8) and the same in regards to rows with `grid-row-end`.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Also be aware of css [repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).  your code could look like `grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);`, much less repitition ;)

Comment: and if you really wanted to go the extra mile, there's [grid shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) too. `grid: repeat(8, 1fr) / repeat(12, 1fr);`